# Re: Correct MongoDb Relationships

Tags: mongodb

Hi clever MongoDB people,

I am extremely new to Mongo DB and am trying to teach myself coding but I am battling with the practical side of collections.

I am attempting to create an employee management system and would like to know how do I get the different schemas/collections to only deal with the individual User’s employees.

A user will register using this schema;

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  companyName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: "customer",
  },
  CreatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: () => Date.now(),
  },

  UpdatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: () => Date.now(),
  },
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema:
);
module.exports = User;
```

Then the system takes them to a Profile page where they create a profile;
Profile Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  contactPerson: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  companyName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  mobileNo: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  workNo: {
    type: String,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  industry: {
    type: String,
  },
  CreatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: () => Date.now(),
  },
  UpdatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: () => Date.now(),
  },
});

const Profile = mongoose.model("Profile", ProfileSchema);
module.exports = Profile;
```

Then they can add their employees.
Employee Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
  userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  employeeNo: {
    type: String,
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  employeeName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  surname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
  },
  race: {
    type: String,
  },
  passportNo: {
    type: String,
  },
  IDnumber: {
    type: Number,
  },
  DOB: {
    type: Date,
  },
  aka: {
    type: String,
  },
  midName: {
    type: String,
  },
  marriage: {
    type: String,
  },
  passportExpires: {
    type: Date,
  },
  mobileNo: {
    type: String,
  },
  empEmail: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  CreatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: () => Date.now(),
  },
  UpdatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: () => Date.now(),
  },
});

const Employee = mongoose.model("Employee", EmployeeSchema);
module.exports = Employee;
```

Once an employee has been created there are various schemas connected with the employee, such as Personal contact details schema, Job details schema, Emergency contact details schema and so on.
This is my Emergency contact details schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const EmergencySchema = new Schema({
  userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  emergContactPerson: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  emergWorkNo: {
    type: String,
  },
  emergMobileNo1: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  emergMobileNo2: {
    type: String,
  },
  medicAidName: {
    type: String,
  },
  medicPlan: {
    type: String,
  },
  medicMemberNo: {
    type: String,
  },
  medicDepCode: {
    type: Number,
  },
  CreatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: () => Date.now(),
  },
  UpdatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: () => Date.now(),
  },
});

const Emergency = mongoose.model("Emergency", EmergencySchema);
module.exports = Emergency;
```

My question is How do I create a one-to-many relationship between my schemas so that each User will only see their employees and their personal details?

Please can you help me?

Comment: You're designing the DB as if you're working with a relational DB. I'd combine most of the objects you've listed into a single document.  e.g. User schema would have an EmergencyContact list (with your structure.) All these "dependent objects" are always queried in the context of the main user, so it should be attached to the main object.) For things like employee's direct reports, you can add a list of their employee ids under the manager. For querying, you'd get direct reports' employee IDs from main User collection and then query employee details as a separate query.

Comment: Thank-you RJ, I appreciate your reply. I did combine most of the objects you've listed into a single document, but I think it was too large as some of the information in the schema did not reflect in schema in MongoDB Atlas and this is why I made the schemas smaller. But you are correct, I am thinking relational database (my background is MS Excel). Thanks again JR.